# Run Time Error 1004, cannot qualify object

Tags: excel, vba, object, runtime

Attached you find a snippet of an Excel macro, in which the part in the for-loop always throws an error:

> run-time error 1004 "application defined or object defined error"

I have checked online and it is advised to correct the object's qualification by adding a dot before the `cells(xy)` expression. However, if I change the code to `Range(.Cells(xyz))`, I am given another error:

> invalid or unqualified reference

Any advice on how to fix this problem?

```
    Sub Run()

Dim n As Integer
n = Worksheets("Results").Cells(10, 8).Value
For i = 1 To n
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Worksheets("VBA").Range(Cells(1, i + 3), Cells(12, i + 3)).Value = Worksheets("Results").Range("F3:F14").Value
Next i

Worksheets("Results").Range("J3:L14").Value = Worksheets("VBA").Range("A1:C12").Value
Worksheets("VBA").Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(12, i + 3)).Clear

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to fully qualify all cells and ranges.

When putting the "." before cells you need to be inside a with block as such:

```
With Worksheets("VBA")
    .Range(.Cells(1, i + 3), .Cells(12, i + 3)).Value = Worksheets("Results").Range("F3:F14").Value
End with
```

This basically is saying the everytime a function starts with "." it is the same as having `Worksheets("VBA")` in front: `Worksheets("VBA").Cells(....)`. without all the typing.